# Launching external program from Adobe Illustrator Actions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

Is it possible to record/create an Actions-macro in Adobe Illustrator that first saves a copy of the currently open file as an SVG-file into a certain directory and then executes an external Windows program?

If that is not possible, can I create a link to the external Windows program in Illustrator's menu somewhere?

Comment: Sounds like you'd be satisfied if you just set a hotkey for the application.

Comment: You can launch application "from Illustrator" via scripting. To nudge you into a direction of some sort... [Here's a javascript example of that.](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/0e11664aa1642a564d33)